# How to fix broken packages?

Tags: system-installation

How can i fix those broken packages? i cant's install anything on the system and i think tha's the error:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

A quick DuckDuckGo search got these results, I hope they help.

https://appuals.com/fix-unable-correct-problems-held-broken-packages/

https://omgfoss.com/how-to-fix-broken-packages-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/